# When will monit actually start or restart a service

Tags: monit, application-monitoring

Can someone please let me know on what basis monit decides that its time to restart an application? For instance, if I want monit to monitor my web application, what information should I provide to monit based on which it will restart?

thanks

Update:
I was able to kind of make it work using the following monit config

```
check host altamides with address web.dev1.ams
if failed port 80 with protocol http
      then alert
```

However, I was wondering if I can use any absolute URL of my application.  Something like `http://foo:5453/test/url/1.html/`

Can someone help me on that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monit by himself will not restart any service, but you can provide to it the rules you want to perform it, you can do something like

```
check process couchdb with pidfile /usr/local/var/run/couchdb/couchdb.pid
    start program = "/etc/init.d/couchdb start"
    stop program  = "/etc/init.d/couchdb stop"
    if cpu > 60% for 2 cycles then alert
    if cpu > 80% for 5 cycles then restart
    if memory usage > 70% MB for 5 cycles then restart
```

```
check host mmonit.com with address mmonit.com
      if failed port 80 protocol http then alert
      if failed port 443 protocol https then alert
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was wondering if there is a provision where I can pass some URL of my web application which the monit can keep checking for HTTP 200 on a regular interval.  And in case it does not get 200 then restart the application.  Is this possible using monit?

Comment: Sure you can, I suggest you to go to monit's website and get more examples, I added a snippet to the original answer

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer from monit help page

```
 if failed
    port 80
    protocol http
    request "/data/show?a=b&c=d"
 then restart
```